# Can we implement sections inside a section of UITableView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Suppose there is a `UITableView` with 2 sections A and B. Now in both sections, multiple objects are to be shown with details, e.g. if the object is car, then there are multiple cars, with name, color, mileage which are to be shown in the object. So how to approach the problem in an optimal way given that we have to implement it with `UITableView`?

I provided 2 sections to `UITableView`. Then, I'm showing the objects as rows inside the sections. Then if I am were to show only 3 details of an object, then I'll provide number of rows as 3*(No of objects). The following code is written inside `UITableViewCell` class and is called from `UIViewController` holding the `UITableView` object's datasource method cellForRowAt()

```swift
func configureSectionACellWith(indexPath: IndexPath, data: [Car]) {
   var row = indexPath.row
   row = row % 3
   switch row {
   case 0: carNameLabel.text = data[indexPath.row/3].name
   case 1: colorLabel.text = data[indexPath.row/3].color
   case 2: mileageLabel.text = data[indexPath.row/3].mileage
   default:
       break
   }
}
```

Similarly, for configuring cells of Section B, the above code was repeated.

But as you might see, lots of things are hard-coded, like row = row % 3, and will be difficult for a new developer to understand the code. Also there is repetition of code(Configuring section A and B's cells).
Is there any other way, which is of course optimal to tackle the situation?

Comment: I can't see any reason to implement sections inside sections.  You should use a custom `IUTableViewCell` with a layout that can show all your detail for the Car. You can build "sections" into the cell design if that's the look you are going for.  This way lets you exploit the functionality that  `UITableView` provides 'out of the box' - see example below.  Otherwise you'll be working against how `UITableView` has been designed.

Answer (score 0):

If the layout/details are likely to be the same for each Section, you can just create one type of cell and use it in both section:

```
class DetailCell: UITableViewCell {
  static let cellID = "DetailCell"
 //set up all the images/labels etc

  func configure(with car: Car) {
    label1.text = car.name
    label2.text = car.color
    label3.text = car.mileage
  }
  func configure(with other: SomeOtherType) {. //whatever Section B displays
    label1.text = other.property1
    label2.text = other.property2
    label3.text = other.property3
  }
}
```

You don't need to worry about indexpaths or rows for the cell definition.  That's done in the dataSource & delegate functions.

You'll set the number of rows in each section the `UITableViewDataSource`'s `numberOfRows` method, and create all your cells in the `cellForRowAt` method.  I'll not repeat all the detail here - there are 100s of tutorials and blogs on tableViews - but will give you summary examples so you know what you're heading towards:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.register(DetailCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: DetailCell.cellID)
   //any other setup
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   switch section :
   case 0: return carsArray.count //if you're showing cars in section A
   case 1: return someOtherArray.count //whatever you;re showing in section B
   default: return 0
   }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DetailCell.cellID, for: indexPath)
  if indexPath.section == 0 {
    cell.configure(with: carsArray[indexPath.row])
  } else if section == 1 {
    cell.configure(with: someOtherArray[indexPath.row])
  }
  //do any further cell set up
  return cell
}
```